# Python attributes from variables?

Tags: python

I want to set x from variables in self.x.
For example

```
for i in range(72)
    self.("entry" + "%s" %(i)) = None
```

Briefly i want to set all entry1, entry2, ... ,entry72 to None like this in short way.

```
self.entry1 = None
self.entry2 = None
self.entry3 = None
self.entry4 = None
.
.
self.entry72 = None
```

in short way. But i take

```
        print self.("entry" + "%s" %(i))
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to set self.attibutes from variables?

Comment: consider instead having a single list, `self.entries`, as an attribute.

Comment: yeah, i can't think of a possible case when it's ever a good idea to have that many numbered variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use built-in [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#setattr) function to set dynamically named attributes:

```
for i in range(72):
    setattr(self, 'entry{0}'.format(x), None)
```

As others have pointed out in comments, there are probably no use-cases for 72 attributes named like that. While this will work, consider using different data type, e.g. dictionary:

```
self.entries = {}
for i in range(72):
    self.entries[i] = None
```